# How to retain values on textbox after going to other page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[image: Here my Enroll.aspx page, when I click add subject it will go to add.apsx page.]On top is my enroll.aspx page, while add.aspx is at bottom.

After I input all data on textboxes, I want to go to add.aspx page, then after that I want to go back on enroll.aspx[image: This is my add.apsx page] page which I input all the data.But if press back all the values on textboxes will be gone. How can I retain those values when I go back?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to do that. What have you tried? Can you show some code?

Comment: Put the values into an array and stored the array in a Session variable

Comment: Im noob in asp.net, how can I use session variable?

Comment: @VDWWD I just have Response.Redirect on my back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a crude code example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim saveText As String = ""

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    saveText = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Public Sub refreshForm()
    TextBox1.Text = saveText
End SubEnd Class
```

Comment: After I press back there were no values displayed on my textbox?

Comment: I did say my example was crude...lol.  I'm not sure how your are moving from form to form, so I changed the example to make it more generic.

Comment: call Form1.refreshForm() from the back button handler.

Comment: I figured it out. I use session to transfer all data to another page and use session again to bring it back to previous page. hahaha. Thanks for all your help.